# Values in the array do not match each other

Tags: python, arrays

Code :

```
while True:
   a=ser.readline()[:-2].decode()
   print(a)
```

Outuput :

```
STREAM-ORIGIN
F`(?p:R@;V%j3y
STREAM-END
```

---

Code :

```
while True:
   a=ser.readline()[:-2].decode()
   datasets.append(a)
   print(datasets)
```

Output :

```
['STREAM-ORIGIN\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
 'F`(?p:R@;V%j3y\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
 'STREAM-END\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']
```

- I want to save it to the list as the values I printed in the first output, but I can't even decode it, please can someone helpp

Comment: What type is a? What type is datasets?

Comment: The problem here is quite obvious, isn't it?  Your serial protocol is reading a bunch of nulls.  So, just get rid of them.  `a = ser.readline()[:-2].rstrip(0).decode()`.

Comment: Values taken from an rf circuit via the fpga board @NicholasHunter

Comment: I didn't ask about the values or where the values come from. I asked what type they are.

Comment: Before .decode() is bytes, after .decode() it becomes str @NicholasHunter

Comment: I inserted the code you said I received an error like this:TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int' @TimRoberts

Comment: Your question is why the arrays don't "match" each other?--by which you seem to mean, why do they look different when I print them? And the answer is probably that they are different types and define different \_\_str\_\_ methods. So they look different when you print them, but the actual data might be exactly the same.

Comment: My goal is to collect this data in a list and combine it into a string. The reason I get the data piece by piece is because the rf card sends 32bit values at a time. When I call the values in the list one by one and try to make a string, the values are deflecting because (\r\x00) these are breaking the structure and if I get them with a command like .replace (), maybe there will really be a data like (\r\x00) and I will destroy it with a mistake. I'm looking for a way to fix this problem. @NicholasHunter

Comment: I need to get the values as I got in the output of the print () function @NicholasHunter

Comment: Well, then, use `rstrip(b'\x00')`.